# Не активная ссылка Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть менюшка, есть пункт Фото. Как сделать его не активным?

Меню в хедере вызывается строкой `<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=first'); ?>`

Само меню объявлено в фанкшене строй

```
function register_main_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'nav' =>__('Меню навигации'), 
        )
    );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор меню вордпресс, помимо общих классов, присваивает каждому пункту меню уникальный id. Допустим, id пункта "Фото" `menu-item-7773`, тогда с помощью jQuery это решается так:

```
$('#menu-item-7773>a').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //отменяем переход по ссылке
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Пункт меню создавать как "произвольная  ссылка", а не как "страница". 
Затем вместо ссылки поставить #.